# Reflection PropertyInfo.GetValue

Tags: c#, reflection, ssis

I am new to using reflection in C#. Any help is much appreciated.

PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) gives me a object value.

If the value of the column is null in the database, I get a Null exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ColumnIsNullException: The column has a null value.

How to handle this situation? I should loop through all the columns and leave the columns which have a null value.

Comment: How is this line of code connected to your database? What is `obj`?

Comment: I am writing this in SSIS Script component. Getting the values based on the column Name in each row.

Comment: I agree with Peter... this doesn't make sense as the code you provided has nothing to do with a Database.

Comment: Property Info columnValue = GetPropertyInfoValue(Row, column); if (columnValue.GetValue(Row, null) != null) { object value; value = columnValue.GetValue(Row, null); } ... this is what i am trying to do

Comment: I am reflecting aganist Input0buffer Row. I am using it in SSIS Script component I am trying to get the values of some columns in each row.  In the above code ..Row is Input0Buffer Row and column is the Column Name and ColumnValue is PropertyInfo

Answer (score 7):

You can check for 'Null' directly as follows

```
if(propInfo.GetValue(this, null) != null) {
}
```

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.' is what I get when I put that in.

Answer (score 3):

The getter of that property is throwing an excepting. It's trying to tell you that the property doesn't have a value.

You should be able to check `PropertyName_IsNull` (Where *PropertyName* is the name of the property) to check if the property is null first. If it is null, handle appropriately, otherwise use the code you've already written.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136045.aspx#sectionToggle2):

> A <column>_IsNull property for each selected input column. This property is also read-only or read/write depending on the Usage Type specified for the column.

Comment: Property Info columnValue = GetPropertyInfoValue(Row, column);
                if (columnValue.GetValue(Row, null) != null)
                {
                    object value;
                    value = columnValue.GetValue(Row, null);
                }     ... this is what i am trying to do.

Comment: I am reflecting aganist Input0buffer Row. I am using it in SSIS Script component I am trying to get the values of some columns in each row.   Row is Input0Buffer Row and column is the Column Name and ColumnValue is PropertyInfo.

Answer (score 2):

`PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null)` is executing the property get method on the object `obj`. The exception is being thrown in that get method. You need to look at the property get method you're invoking and determine when/why an exception is being thrown.

Comment: The value is null for that column is null in the database. i need to handle that situation for null values.

Comment: I get that, but without knowing what property of what Type `PropertyInfo` represents, it's hard to give an accurate answer. What are you reflecting against, a DataSet? What property are trying to read?

Comment: I am reflecting aganist Input0buffer Row. I am using it in SSIS Script component

Comment: I am trying to get the values of  some columns  in each row.